chart js stacked scale overrides x labels
i built a chart with multiple stacked y scales.
the x axis shows a timeline, logically common to all datasets.
the x values don't overlap, as each dataset has it's own length and values.
most datasets show their x values together on the x axis, but one of them seems to take over the whole axis, displaying only it's value.
i'm talking about the dataset title.
please see that if "title" is visible, there's only one value on x, but if "title" is clicked, so it's hidden, all the x values are displayed normally.


            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@^2"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^2"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>
            
            <div class="chart" style="height:100vh; width:100vw">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script>
            const data = {"datasets":[{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"title","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y00Title","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"green","pointStyle":false,"datalabels":{"color":"black","backgroundColor":"yellow","align":"right"},"id":"id_title","data":[{"x":1254229397000,"y":0,"label":{"text":"2009-09-29"}}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"price","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y01Prices","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"green","pointStyle":"cross","pointRadius":0,"id":"id_price","data":[{"x":1254229397000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254229825000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254230844000,"y":51.83},{"x":1254230859000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254230990000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254230990005,"y":51.76},{"x":1254230990008,"y":51.77},{"x":1254230990011,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230991002,"y":51.79},{"x":1254230991003,"y":51.76},{"x":1254230994006,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230994007,"y":51.75},{"x":1254230995000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254230996000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230996001,"y":51.74},{"x":1254231000000,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231002000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231002001,"y":51.64},{"x":1254231003000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231009000,"y":51.65},{"x":1254231011000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231012000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231065000,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231072000,"y":51.69},{"x":1254231088000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231104000,"y":51.656},{"x":1254231109000,"y":51.63},{"x":1254231127000,"y":51.64},{"x":1254231141000,"y":51.63},{"x":1254231181000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231218000,"y":51.734},{"x":1254231222000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254231223000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254231242000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254231242005,"y":51.79},{"x":1254231304000,"y":51.73},{"x":1254231304007,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231304008,"y":51.73},{"x":1254231304009,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231367000,"y":51.8073},{"x":1254231369000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254231479000,"y":51.81},{"x":1254231566000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254231573000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254231601000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254231657000,"y":51.8002},{"x":1254231671000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254231672000,"y":51.87},{"x":1254231687000,"y":51.91},{"x":1254231688000,"y":51.92},{"x":1254231726000,"y":51.87},{"x":1254231847000,"y":51.86},{"x":1254231949000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254231950000,"y":51.8296},{"x":1254232135000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232175000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254232185000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232203000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254232236000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232253000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232261000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232268000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232272000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254232274000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232304000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254232354000,"y":51.82},{"x":1254232365000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232468000,"y":51.7872},{"x":1254232474000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254232489000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232509000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254232533000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232594000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254232606000,"y":51.9},{"x":1254232711000,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232757000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232757005,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232757010,"y":51.93},{"x":1254232767000,"y":51.96},{"x":1254232770000,"y":51.93},{"x":1254232778000,"y":51.94},{"x":1254232796000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232796005,"y":51.94},{"x":1254232797000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232800000,"y":51.91},{"x":1254232800005,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232800010,"y":51.91},{"x":1254232800011,"y":51.88},{"x":1254232801002,"y":51.85},{"x":1254232801007,"y":51.82},{"x":1254232801008,"y":51.81},{"x":1254232801013,"y":51.89},{"x":1254232801014,"y":51.88},{"x":1254232802000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254232804000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232805000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232807000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232807003,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232808000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232815000,"y":51.7495}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"nlv","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y03NLV","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"gold","pointStyle":"star","id":"id_nlv","data":[{"x":1254229397002,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966008,"y":21991.370000000003},{"x":1254232966009,"y":21987.17},{"x":1254232966024,"y":21978.7},{"x":1254232966026,"y":21977.9},{"x":1254236453001,"y":21946.02},{"x":1254254400004,"y":21972.059999999998}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","label":"value-USD","yAxisID":"y02Balance","pointStyle":"line","borderColor":"red","id":"id_value-USD","data":[{"x":1254229825000,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966000,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966003,"y":15759.87},{"x":1254232966006,"y":12665.67},{"x":1254232966018,"y":6425.700000000001},{"x":1254232966022,"y":4364.9000000000015},{"x":1254236447004,"y":2821.500000000001},{"x":1254239179000,"y":2821.500000000001},{"x":1254254400004,"y":2821.500000000001}],"animation":false}],"labels":[]};
            
            function labelattr(context, attr)
            {
                let label = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].label;
                if (label) {
                    return label[attr];
                }
                return null;
            }
            const config = {
    "type": "line",
    "plugins": [
        {
            "id": "custom_canvas_background_color",
            "beforeDraw": (chart, args, options) => {
        const {ctx} = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = options.color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
        ctx.restore();
    },
            "defaults": {
                "color": "lightGreen"
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "animation": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "normalized": true,
        "parsing": false,
        "interaction": {
            "mode": "point",
            "axis": "xy",
            "includeInvisible": true
        },
        "ticks": {
            "format": {
                "maximumFractionDigits": 4
            }
        },
        "plugins": {
            "custom_canvas_background_color": {
                "color": "white"
            },
            "datalabels": {
                "backgroundColor": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'backgroundColor') ||
                                context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                "borderRadius": 4,
                "color": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'color');
                        },
                "font": {
                    "size": "8px"
                },
                "formatter": function(value, context) {
                            //return value;
                            return labelattr(context, 'text');
                        },
                "anchor": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'anchor');
                        },
                "align": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'align');
                        },
                "padding": 1
            },
            "title": {
                "display": true,
                "text": "initial title",
                "fontSize": 14,
                "fontFamily": "Roboto",
                "fontColor": "#474747"
            },
            "legend": {
                "title": {
                    "display": true,
                    "text": "Datasets",
                    "fontSize": 14,
                    "fontFamily": "Roboto",
                    "fontColor": "#474747"
                },
                "display": true,
                "position": "bottom",
                "labels": {
                    "usePointStyle": true,
                    "boxWidth": 9,
                    "fontColor": "#474747",
                    "fontFamily": "6px Montserrat",
                    "filter": (item, chart) => {
                                return (item.text !== 'hidden');
                            }
                }
            },
            "tooltip": {
                "itemSort": (a, b) => {
                            return ((a.raw.x > b.raw.x) - (a.raw.x < b.raw.x));
                        }
            }
        },
        "scales": {
            "x": {
                "type": "time",
                "time": {
                    "unit": "minute",
                    "tooltipFormat": "HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                    "tooltipFormat0": "x",
                    "displayFormats": {
                        "millisecond": "HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                        "second": "HH:mm:ss",
                        "minute": "HH:mm:ss",
                        "millisecond0": "x",
                        "second0": "x",
                        "minute0": "x"
                    }
                },
                "adapters": {
                    "date": {
                        "zone": "America/New_York"
                    }
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                }
            },
            "y03NLV": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": "auto",
                "stackWeight": 0.5,
                "title": {
                    "text": "nlv",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y02Balance": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": "auto",
                "stackWeight": 0.5,
                "title": {
                    "text": "balance",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y01Prices": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "stackWeight": 3,
                "title": {
                    "text": "prices",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "border": {
                    "display": true,
                    "color": "green"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y00Title": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": true,
                "stackWeight": 0.2,
                "title": {
                    "text": "title",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            }
        }
    }
};
            config.plugins.push(ChartDataLabels);
            config.data = data;
            
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
            chart = new Chart(
                ctx,
                config,
            );
            </script>
        



i would like to see all the x values, irrespective which datasets are visible.
could you please advise?

Could you simplify your code to get a minimal, reproducible example. I mean, if you can, please remove the plugins, options, etc., that are not part of the problem.

I'd start by removing  source: "data" in options.scales.x.ticks; you can't possibly want to see all the x labels for each of the 100+ data points.

I kindly thank you, @Éric and @kikon for considering my question. My chart datasets are being built and filled as the simulated data is streaming, and I automatically create the snapshot in the snippet. Indeed, only the datalabels plugin is needed for the snippet, in order to display a label as a title at the x location of the beginning of day. But, probably since this title dataset is being rendered first, and it has x values only once a day, I see no other hour values on the x axis. Should I add {x: x, y: null} in the title ds for each datum in any ds?

To resolve my problem, I rearranged my data as follows:
As I wanted all the x labels, from all datasets to be visible,
I added all that labels (x values) to the dataset displayed first.
My example code is doing this after the chart is being built,
but I think it could be done better and easier
before the chart is created/displayed.
To improve performance, it could be better to show only the first
dataset x labels. Please note, sorting of the x labels may be needed.


            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@^2"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^2"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>
            
            <div class="chart" style="height:100vh; width:100vw">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script>
            const data = {"datasets":[{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"title","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y00Title","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"green","pointStyle":false,"datalabels":{"color":"black","backgroundColor":"yellow","align":"right"},"id":"id_title","data":[{"x":1254229397000,"y":0,"label":{"text":"2009-09-29"}}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"price","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y01Prices","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"green","pointStyle":"cross","pointRadius":0,"id":"id_price","data":[{"x":1254229397000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254229825000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254230844000,"y":51.83},{"x":1254230859000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254230990000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254230990005,"y":51.76},{"x":1254230990008,"y":51.77},{"x":1254230990011,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230991002,"y":51.79},{"x":1254230991003,"y":51.76},{"x":1254230994006,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230994007,"y":51.75},{"x":1254230995000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254230996000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254230996001,"y":51.74},{"x":1254231000000,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231002000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231002001,"y":51.64},{"x":1254231003000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231009000,"y":51.65},{"x":1254231011000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231012000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231065000,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231072000,"y":51.69},{"x":1254231088000,"y":51.67},{"x":1254231104000,"y":51.656},{"x":1254231109000,"y":51.63},{"x":1254231127000,"y":51.64},{"x":1254231141000,"y":51.63},{"x":1254231181000,"y":51.71},{"x":1254231218000,"y":51.734},{"x":1254231222000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254231223000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254231242000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254231242005,"y":51.79},{"x":1254231304000,"y":51.73},{"x":1254231304007,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231304008,"y":51.73},{"x":1254231304009,"y":51.72},{"x":1254231367000,"y":51.8073},{"x":1254231369000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254231479000,"y":51.81},{"x":1254231566000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254231573000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254231601000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254231657000,"y":51.8002},{"x":1254231671000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254231672000,"y":51.87},{"x":1254231687000,"y":51.91},{"x":1254231688000,"y":51.92},{"x":1254231726000,"y":51.87},{"x":1254231847000,"y":51.86},{"x":1254231949000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254231950000,"y":51.8296},{"x":1254232135000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232175000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254232185000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232203000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254232236000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232253000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232261000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232268000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232272000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254232274000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232304000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254232354000,"y":51.82},{"x":1254232365000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232468000,"y":51.7872},{"x":1254232474000,"y":51.8},{"x":1254232489000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232509000,"y":51.79},{"x":1254232533000,"y":51.78},{"x":1254232594000,"y":51.84},{"x":1254232606000,"y":51.9},{"x":1254232711000,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232757000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232757005,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232757010,"y":51.93},{"x":1254232767000,"y":51.96},{"x":1254232770000,"y":51.93},{"x":1254232778000,"y":51.94},{"x":1254232796000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232796005,"y":51.94},{"x":1254232797000,"y":51.95},{"x":1254232800000,"y":51.91},{"x":1254232800005,"y":51.92},{"x":1254232800010,"y":51.91},{"x":1254232800011,"y":51.88},{"x":1254232801002,"y":51.85},{"x":1254232801007,"y":51.82},{"x":1254232801008,"y":51.81},{"x":1254232801013,"y":51.89},{"x":1254232801014,"y":51.88},{"x":1254232802000,"y":51.74},{"x":1254232804000,"y":51.77},{"x":1254232805000,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232807000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232807003,"y":51.76},{"x":1254232808000,"y":51.75},{"x":1254232815000,"y":51.7495}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","isQuote":false,"label":"nlv","beginAtZero":false,"yAxisID":"y03NLV","stepped":false,"spanGaps":false,"hidden":0,"borderColor":"gold","pointStyle":"star","id":"id_nlv","data":[{"x":1254229397002,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966008,"y":21991.370000000003},{"x":1254232966009,"y":21987.17},{"x":1254232966024,"y":21978.7},{"x":1254232966026,"y":21977.9},{"x":1254236453001,"y":21946.02},{"x":1254254400004,"y":21972.059999999998}],"animation":false},{"type":"line","label":"value-USD","yAxisID":"y02Balance","pointStyle":"line","borderColor":"red","id":"id_value-USD","data":[{"x":1254229825000,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966000,"y":21999.84},{"x":1254232966003,"y":15759.87},{"x":1254232966006,"y":12665.67},{"x":1254232966018,"y":6425.700000000001},{"x":1254232966022,"y":4364.9000000000015},{"x":1254236447004,"y":2821.500000000001},{"x":1254239179000,"y":2821.500000000001},{"x":1254254400004,"y":2821.500000000001}],"animation":false}],"labels":[]};
            
            function labelattr(context, attr)
            {
                let label = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].label;
                if (label) {
                    return label[attr];
                }
                return null;
            }
            const config = {
    "type": "line",
    "plugins": [
        {
            "id": "custom_canvas_background_color",
            "beforeDraw": (chart, args, options) => {
        const {ctx} = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = options.color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
        ctx.restore();
    },
            "defaults": {
                "color": "lightGreen"
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "animation": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "normalized": true,
        "parsing": false,
        "interaction": {
            "mode": "point",
            "axis": "xy",
            "includeInvisible": true
        },
        "ticks": {
            "format": {
                "maximumFractionDigits": 4
            }
        },
        "plugins": {
            "custom_canvas_background_color": {
                "color": "white"
            },
            "datalabels": {
                "backgroundColor": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'backgroundColor') ||
                                context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                        },
                "borderRadius": 4,
                "color": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'color');
                        },
                "font": {
                    "size": "8px"
                },
                "formatter": function(value, context) {
                            //return value;
                            return labelattr(context, 'text');
                        },
                "anchor": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'anchor');
                        },
                "align": function(context) {
                            return labelattr(context, 'align');
                        },
                "padding": 1
            },
            "title": {
                "display": true,
                "text": "initial title",
                "fontSize": 14,
                "fontFamily": "Roboto",
                "fontColor": "#474747"
            },
            "legend": {
                "title": {
                    "display": true,
                    "text": "Datasets",
                    "fontSize": 14,
                    "fontFamily": "Roboto",
                    "fontColor": "#474747"
                },
                "display": true,
                "position": "bottom",
                "labels": {
                    "usePointStyle": true,
                    "boxWidth": 9,
                    "fontColor": "#474747",
                    "fontFamily": "6px Montserrat",
                    "filter": (item, chart) => {
                                return (item.text !== 'hidden');
                            }
                }
            },
            "tooltip": {
                "itemSort": (a, b) => {
                            return ((a.raw.x > b.raw.x) - (a.raw.x < b.raw.x));
                        }
            }
        },
        "scales": {
            "x": {
                "type": "time",
                "time": {
                    "unit": "minute",
                    "tooltipFormat": "HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                    "tooltipFormat0": "x",
                    "displayFormats": {
                        "millisecond": "HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                        "second": "HH:mm:ss",
                        "minute": "HH:mm:ss",
                        "millisecond0": "x",
                        "second0": "x",
                        "minute0": "x"
                    }
                },
                "adapters": {
                    "date": {
                        "zone": "America/New_York"
                    }
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                }
            },
            "y03NLV": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": "auto",
                "stackWeight": 0.5,
                "title": {
                    "text": "nlv",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y02Balance": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": "auto",
                "stackWeight": 0.5,
                "title": {
                    "text": "balance",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y01Prices": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "stackWeight": 3,
                "title": {
                    "text": "prices",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "border": {
                    "display": true,
                    "color": "green"
                },
                "offset": true
            },
            "y00Title": {
                "type": "linear",
                "position": "left",
                "stack": "data",
                "display": true,
                "stackWeight": 0.2,
                "title": {
                    "text": "title",
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "source": "data"
                },
                "offset": true
            }
        }
    }
};
            config.plugins.push(ChartDataLabels);
            config.data = data;
            
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
            chart = new Chart(
                ctx,
                config,
            );
            //the following code ilustrates the need to have all the x values
            //present in the first displayed dataset, in order to be seen.
            //in practice the "patch" should be done 
            //before the data is being added to the chart.
            let titleData = chart.data.datasets
            .filter(ds => ds.yAxisID == "y00Title")
            .map(ds => ds.data)[0];
            chart.data.datasets
            .filter(ds => ds.yAxisID != "y00Title")
            .forEach(ds => {
                titleData.push(...ds.data.map(one => ({x:one.x, y: null})));
            });
            chart.update();
            </script>
        



